# How can I convert a list of strings into numeric values?

Tags: python

How can I convert a list of strings (each of which represents a number, i.e. `[‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’]`) into numeric values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map)([int](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int), ["1", "2", "3"])

gives

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It should pointed out that `map` is a built in function that applies the function `int` to every element of your list.  Then returns a list of the results of that function.

Comment: I keep forgeting that functional programming stuff like map exists, Thanks for reminding me of another nice way to modify lists.

Comment: This is homework.  Why provide a full answer?  Why not provide hints, a direction and -- above all -- a reference to the int function?

Comment: @S.Lott: It's been a while since I've had any homework. Man, what kind of school is that where the task is to look up a library function and have problems with doing it? BTW: I'll edit references to official docs.

Comment: @Andrew: it returns list of results only in py2k, in py3k it returns a generator that needs to be converted into list explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) and a [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
>>> i = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> [int(k) for k in i]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

As Long as the strings are of the form '1'  rather than 'one' then you can use the int() function.

Some sample code would be

```
strList = ['1','2','3']
numList = [int(x) for x in strList]
```

Or without the list comprehension

```
strList = ['1','2','3']
numList = []
for x in strList:
    numList.append(int(x))
```

Both examples iterate through the list on strings and apply the int() function to the value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
>>> int('5')
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
map(int, ['1', '2', '3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['1','2','3']
map(lambda x: int(x),a)

> [1, 2, 3]
```